# How do you detect a windows firewall change?

Tags: .net, com, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

Is there any way to get a notification / event when a rule is changed or the firewall enabled / disabled ?

(I'm using the FirewallAPI.DLL COM interface, but it doesnt seem to have any way of notification - you'd have to keep polling and iterating through the rules, which would add a lot of overhead when you don't expect them to change very often)